# Unable to interpolates variable with Start-Service in powershell

Tags: powershell, powercli

I'm new to the powerscript and have issue to interpolation Start-Service sentence with a variable.
I understand that '' which will change the var into exact sentence but have out of idea to make it run with the sentence `'Start-Service "Services name"'`
Below is the script that I try to run it with the powercli. Any help would be much appreciated.

`Invoke-VMScript -vm $vm -GuestUser $GUser -GuestPassword $GPass 'Start-Service "$servicename"'`

Comment: Put the `" "` on the outside: `"Start-Service '$servicename'"`

Comment: I think with the quote '$servicename' the output was exactly the Start-Service $servicename instead of the variable value. Below is the error:
<code> Invoke-VMScript : 7/27/2018 10:35:13 AM    Invoke-VMScript        Value cannot be found for the mandatory parameter VM
At Test.ps1:24 char:17
+     Invoke-VMScript <<<<  -vm $vm -GuestUser $GUser -GuestPassword $GPass "St
art-Service '$servicename'" + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-VMScript], VimException + FullyQualifiedErrorId Core_BaseCmdlet_UnknownError,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.InvokeVmScript </code>

Comment: The outside quote marks a PowerShell string. `"x"` is a double quoted string and will do variable replacement. `'x'` is a single quoted string and will not replace variables. `"x '$y'"` is a double quoted string and will replace variables - the single quotes are not significant, they are characters inside the string. `'x "$y"'` is a single quoted string, and will not replace variables - the double quotes are not significant, they are characters inside the string.

Comment: In your original post, `'Start-Service "$servicename"'` is a single quoted string, and will not replace the variable with the service name. In my suggestion, `"Start-Service '$servicename'"` is a double quoted string, and will replace the variable with the service name. But your error is "*Value cannot be found for the mandatory parameter VM*" - which suggests your `$vm` variable is the problem - it's null, or empty.